# String to integer conversion method using initial value

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

**bin/move:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative '../lib/move.rb'

puts "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!"
board = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
puts "Where would you like to go?"
index = gets.strip

input_to_index(index)
move(board, index, user_marker = "X")
display_board(board)
```

**lib/move.rb:**

```
def display_board(board)
  puts " #{board[0]} | #{board[1]} | #{board[2]} "
  puts "-----------"
  puts " #{board[3]} | #{board[4]} | #{board[5]} "
  puts "-----------"
  puts " #{board[6]} | #{board[7]} | #{board[8]} "
end

def input_to_index(input)
  input = index.to_i - 1
end

def move(board, index, user_marker = "X")
  board[index.to_i] = user_marker
end
```

I ran the code, and got the following result:

```
>ruby bin/move
Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
Where would you like to go?
>6
/home/Tolenno/ttt-5-move-rb-cb-gh-000/lib/move.rb:10:in `input_to_index': undefined local v
ariable or method `index' for main:Object (NameError)
        from bin/move:10:in `<main>'
```

When I run `move`, it uses the `gets` input from the user, and not the new `index` variable from `input_to_index`. Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: No need for the down vote... I am only trying to learn. Is index not defined at 'index = gets.strip'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up the variables, but it can be fixed quite easily.

When gathering the user input, assign it to a variable called `input` (instead of `index`):

```
input = gets.strip
```

Then, pass `input` to `input_to_index` and assign the *result* to a new variable called `index`:

```
index = input_to_index(input)
```

Furthermore, change your `input_to_index` method so it converts the given `input`:

```
def input_to_index(string)
  string.to_i - 1
end
```

I've deliberately changed the argument name to indicate that this is a different variable.

---

#### Alternative

Since `input` is a temporary variable and never used again, you could also inline it and write:

```
index = input_to_index(gets.strip)
```

And `input_to_index` doesn't do that much either. You might consider removing it as well and instead write:

```
index = gets.to_i - 1
```

The above will read a string from the user, convert it to an integer (`to_i` ignores extraneous characters, including newlines), subtract 1 and assign the result to `index`.

---

#### Suggestion

Your methods are related to the Tic Tac Toe board. You could therefore move them into a `Board` class, along with the array (as an instance variable). The change is quite simple:

```
class Board
  def initialize
    @board = Array.new(9, ' ')
  end

  def display
    puts " #{@board[0]} | #{@board[1]} | #{@board[2]} "
    puts "---+---+---"
    puts " #{@board[3]} | #{@board[4]} | #{@board[5]} "
    puts "---+---+---"
    puts " #{@board[6]} | #{@board[7]} | #{@board[8]} "
  end

  def move(index, user_marker = 'X')
    @board[index] = user_marker
  end
end
```

You would use the class like this:

```
puts "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!"
board = Board.new

puts "Where would you like to go?"
index = gets.to_i - 1
board.move(index, 'x')
board.display
```

IMO, this is easier than passing the board around and the code looks a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are wrong. As the error message says, in `move.rb` line 10, within the method body of `input_to_index`, you are using `index`, which is neither defined as a method, nor as a variable.

> Is index not defined at 'index = gets.strip'?

No. The scope of a local variable never goes beyond a single file. You cannot use in `lib/move.rb` a local variable that is defined in `bin/move`.

Comment: No need for the down vote... I am only trying to learn. Is index not defined at 'index = gets.strip'?

Comment: Local variable won’t pass a method scope even within the same file boundaries.

Comment: @mudasobwa You are right. Either my point alone, or your point alone suffices as a reason.